# How to plot scatter data points using colormap after comparing two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code I want to plot scatter points after comparing two numpy arrays `a` and `b`. When a value in the `a` is low then assign a bright color to the corresponding value `b`. E.g when `a` is zero, assign bright color to the value 2(in `b`) on the final graph. I have never plotted data with colors after such a comparison. Please guide me how can we do that?

```
a = np.array([6,2,7,0,1])
b= np.array([-3,-2,0,2,3])
c=np.array([1/3,1/3,1/3,1/3,1/3])
print("lengths:",len(a),len(b),len(c))
fig=plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(b,c,marker='.')
ax.set_xlim(-3,3)
ax.set_ylim(-1/2,1/2)
plt.savefig("./Colormap")`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a color array using `np.where` and supply your conditions. Something like this

```
low_thresh = 1
colors = np.where(a < low_thresh, 'r', 'g')

plt.scatter(a,b,c=colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could do in this way:

```
for el_a, el_b, el_c in zip(a,b,c):
    if el_a < el_b:
        ax.scatter(el_b, el_c , c='lightblue', marker='.')
    else: ax.scatter(el_b, el_c , c='blue', marker='.')
```